# Editing Info.plist of Xcode project using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, info.plist

How can I edit info.plist file of xcode project? I have tried searching a lot but nothing specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An info.plist file can be considered 2 ways. One, it's just a specially formatted text file so thinking that way you can manipulate the text directly. Applescript can read text files, manipulate text, and write text files. Two, it's a basic xml file formatted with apple's tags to create a "plist" file. So you could use xml tools on the file as well. System Events has xml tools. There's also a unix command line program called "defaults" that can work on them as well.

So there's several tools. You need to think about what you want to do, how complicated the task is, and then decide which tool will best fit your requirements.

After you figure out those basics, try some things and come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer.I do have one more doubt if you can help.Can I run an svn checkout terminal command silently(as in not opening a terminal).Right now if I do tell application "Terminal" and run do script it opens the terminal. Also how do I know that checkout is complete?? so that I can go ahead and change plist file in the downloaded project.
I am totally a newbie at applescript!!

Comment: Just use "do shell script" without the "tell app Terminal" code. It runs without using the Terminal straight from applescript. It will receive the return value from your svn command, which I'm assuming you can use to verify if the code completed successfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude..I did run svn co on as an shell script but when it ended I am not sure if I got the return value back.But thanks anyways.